# Getting SVG images picked up by social networks like linkedIn and G+

Tags: facebook, svg, linkedin-api, social-networking

Social networks such as LinkedIn, Facebook and G+ normally display the first big image they find in a web page as a thumbnail when a link is created to that page on the network. Nowever, this doesn't work if the main is an SVG image. Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a programming question.

Comment: Provide a rendered version of your SVG (JPEG/PNG), and specify that as the image to use as thumbnail explicitly.